# Need to test website on my desktop like iPhone 4 on pc

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, wordpress-theming, iphone-4

I am developing a responsive theme where i am facing a problem my client is saying that he is facing some design issues on iPhone 4 i don't have device any one can please guide me how i can test on my desktop same like my client viewing on iPhone 4 i have find and download many simulator and emulator from online every one showing me the correct results(without any issue) but client is continuously saying he has same issue please any one guide me how i can test from windows 7.
Also let me know pixels of iPhone 4 screen.

Comment: can you please let me know the name of software.

Comment: Google is your friend: String: cross browser testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing a web application on every browser and platform is not feasible. See if BrowserStack might solve your web application testing problem. 
The maturation of web standards like CSS and HTML makes it easier to build robust applications, but support and implementation of those standards is not uniform, so thorough testing is necessary to ensure applications perform as expected. The vast number of browsers and devices used in this always connected world, as well as the rapid product development cycle, make this testing a challenge.

This is where the BrowserStack service enters the picture. BrowserStack provides a way to test web applications on different browsers and operating systems via an easy-to-use web interface.

Please take a look
http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Have Browserstack recovered from being hacked yet?

Answer (score 0):

If the source of the problem is just the screen size, you can use your browser dev tools (F12 in firefox/chrome) and set a custom resolution too see how is behaving your css.

You can also use an extension like User Agent Switcher if your site is based on user agent.

If this is not helping, ask your client to take a screenshot or ask his resolution...